# Dates approach for a local cultural events site (Drupal 9)

Tags: date, drupal, drupal-modules

I know I'm not the first not will be the last one to try to deploy an events guide using Drupal. I had a basic one myself some 10 years ago. Starting now from scratch with Drupal 9 I've met with the same doubt I did then: **what can be the best approach to manage dates within the event content type?**

**A) The scenario**

I live in a state with 3 medium cities and several counties. I'm starting with just one city in order to avoid (in the beginning) the location problems. I am also starting being the one and only admin, despite I plan to add some editors (able to add events) in the near future.  I've created 2 different content types in Drupal 9: events & venues.Events do have to be associated to one venue. I want to show on a view all the available events going on on a chosen single date. Those cultural **events can be, as related to dates**:

1. **single date**: e.g a concert happening on Wed 2021/12/01 at 20:00h
2. **different dates**: e.g. a theater play happening on Fri 2021/12/03 at 20:00h + Sat 2021/12/04 at 18:00h & 20:00h + Sun 2021/12/05 at 18:00h
3. **a period of time** (days): e.g. and art exhibition open from Wed 2021/12/01 to Mon 2022/01/31. I don't care about times in this case.
4. I am discarding recurrent dates on purpose (for technical and logistic reasons, see bottom line)

**B) A few date field related modules**

I've checked different modules, including the **core Datetime module**, of course. Because I'm just sketching my project, I'd prefer manage with the proper modules combination rather than adding any custom code.

- core **Datetime module** shows the HTML5 date picker which is 'nice' because of the calendar widget but the time field shows a granularity I don't need (no need of seconds nor minutes in a lower gap than quarters of an hour: :00, :15, :30 & :45). I've thought I could use the 'only date' option of this date field then.
- **Datetime Range module** seems to make the ending date/time mandatory, and that's not the case
- I don't think I'll need the **Recurring Dates Field** as I am not using it (see 4)
- **Smart Date module** looks pretty... smart but I find it overkill for the needs of my project and I am not sure it would suit for all and each of the aforementioned (1, 2, 3) event dates combination
- I found a few other date related modules: Date Augmenter API (not being sure what can improve)

**C) First approach**

With all these in mind I've build a draft of what I guess could solve the main issues:

- Start date (date): **a mandatory Date field (only date)** for the start date (usually same as the ending date)
- Start date (time): **an optional Date field (only time)** for the start date (despite it should be mandatory for cases 1 and 2)
- End date (date): **an optional Date field (only date)** for the ending date (case 3)

and

1. for events with a single date (such as a concert) I'd have to add starting date and time
2. for events happening on different dates and times (such as theater plays, case 2) I'd have to add different nodes with same content and different dates. Multiple values do not seem the right solution as I'm not sure how to group 2 fields -Start date (date) and Start date (time)- so that choosing a second value would ask for both date and time fields
3. for events happening during a period of time (such as art exhibitions) I'd have to add an start and an ending date (no time)

Then when showing 'all events for today', for instance, I'd create a view choosing all the event nodes starting on that date (today's date) and those with an older starting date having a future (or today's) ending date.

...

I believe it somewhat solves it but I'm sure it could be done in a much nicer, simpler (for the events editor), efficient way. I'd be more than happy if you could contribute with any case studies, experiences, knowledge and tips, as well as promoting discussion about this, most probably very common, kind of project when addressed making use of Drupal.

I appreciate your interest reading this long post through. Have a nice day,
h

*I prefer to re-type, say, weekly events if they happen than having non-existent ones because the organizers decided to skip one or simply stop producing the event without prior warning*

Comment: I think I would try this scenario with a complete custom module that povides a new entitytype and the mandatory date fields without a date contribution module. That's easier in my opinion than trying to solve this with a contribution module and press it into this use case.

Comment: Ty @SchwarzDeveloping
I'm sure that would be an accurate solution. But I'm afraid my knowledge on Drupal doesn't go that far. The older I grow the less I know about (everything) coding and Drupal. I'll try to stick to minimum coding here and, in case the project grows successfully, I'll approach some expert coder to redesign it making use of your custom module and entityyipe solution.

Again, thank you very much for your savvy solution.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe that if you want something simple, without code (or few), you have to change the vision of what you want.

Maybe that one content type is not enought to do thoses things.
Create (for exemple, you can add more or less content types) a one representation, multiple representations, long time representation content type.
Then you can override (with Pathauto module) the path of your contents types to target the same path.
Then you agregate everything with searchAPI + views.

Another solution (more code) is add a list of display in your content type.
Example : One representation / Multiple representations / Long time representation.
Then in your template, the date field can be modified with a specific format , depends of the option choosen. (with some controls to display the right format)

With this kind of configuration you can have :

- Start date (timestamp): mandatory /multiple cardinality
- End date (timestamp): optional /simple cardinality

Comment: Ty, @sharklalu. I finlly went with different content types for each of the cases. Sorry I missed your reply until now :-(